# How to find a threshold power to activate passive RFID tag?

Tags: rfid

Is there any minimum power which a low frequency RFID tag needs to power itself? I have yet not found this information from any datasheet of several RFID tags.

I have a simulation, where I know how strong the magnetic field produced by my antenna is at a given distance, and I would like to estimate the detection distance.

For example if some tag could power itself in a 2 mT field, then I could check at what distance the magnetic field would still be strong enough to power the tag.

Comment: yes the there is minimum power required to turn on a passive RFID. I know that for the UHF band the passive RFID tag as a sensitivity of -10dBm. There are journals out there that will have the sensitivity of the LF band. Once the sensitivity is known then you just apply Friis equation to determine the maximum distance.

Comment: What type of tag and what size and technology. There are huge differences.

Comment: @StefanWyss The only requirement for the tag is that it's diameter should be maximum 6mm, the length doesn't matter that much. It should be a passive tag, operating at 125-135kHz frequency.

Comment: @Joey Okey, but I'm struggling to find this information. Almost any article or journal etc. is about UHF. I haven't yet found any information related to LF tags sensitivity.